# Local variable referenced before assignment Python 3.4.5

Tags: python

I'm going through LearnPythonTheHardWay book and I'm stuck on ex35. I decided to create my own game as he asked on Study Drills. I have `gold_room` function that is just like his, but it raises the title's errors on both codes(his and mine).

```
def gold_room():

    print("You enter a room full of gold.")
    print("Do you take the gold and run to the exit or you just walk out with nothing in your hands?")

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "take":
        print("How much do you take?")
        choice_two = input("> ")

        if "0" in choice_two or "1" in choice_two:
            how_much = int(choice_two)
        else:
            print("Man, learn to type a number.")

        if how_much < 50:
            print("You're not greedy. You win!")
            exit(0)
        else:
            print("You greedy bastard!")
            exit(0)
    elif choice == "walk":
        print("You're not greedy. You win!")
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("I don't know what that means")
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'how_much' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving that error because you are referencing the variable `how_much` before any value is assigned to it. :)

This happens at line: `if how_much < 50:`

At that point in code execution, whether `how_much` is defined or not depends on whether the previous condition (`if "0" in choice_two or "1" in choice_two:`) or not.

The code as-written doesn't really make sense; you should only be thinking about how much `how_much` is if the user **has** entered a number, which is what that first condition is supposed to determine.

Try something like this, instead:

```
if "0" in choice_two or "1" in choice_two:
    how_much = int(choice_two)
    if how_much < 50:
        print("You're not greedy. You win!")
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("You greedy bastard!")
        exit(0)
else:
    print("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

Comment: A while loop might help: While choice_two is not 0 or 1 query the input for choice_two again and again.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get it (:

Comment: @MattDMo Didn't know that, just created my account hehe sorry

Comment: @andzedd that's why I commented. Just doing my part to help educate new users.